# Purchase iTunes music on Android and sync it to iPod

Tags: android, music, itunes, ipod

My wife has given up a standard laptop and now only has an Android phone and an Android tablet.  However, she still loves her iPod nano and is struggling to function without a Windows version of iTunes.

Is there an alternative that will allow her to **purchase** music via iTunes on her Android tablet, and allow her to sync it to her iPod?  She does not need to be able to listen to music or stream it like the normal versions of iTunes, she just wants to browse the library and sync it to her iPod.

Are there any options, or does she have to borrow my laptop anytime she wants to browse iTunes and purchase new music?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no iTunes compatible client for Android, so she have to borrow a laptop for that. You didn't ask for hardware recommendations, but iPod Touch is relatively affordable iPod with iTunes and app store support.

Syncing iTunes music to Android is possible, with [TuneSync](http://www.tunesync.com/). According to [this article](http://ipod.about.com/od/advanceditunesuse/a/Itunes-Android-What-Works-And-What-Does-Not.htm), syncing iTunes videos, Apps or iBooks to Android is not possible.

Comment: Generally you can just copy and paste music from your iTunes library to your phone/device. It is DRM-free after all.

Comment: You're right, but I could imagine person with no (personal) laptop doesn't want to do that.

Comment: @Olli you are right, this issue is the only thing keeping her tied to a windows-based machine at all, so it's a matter of purchasing **and** syncing.  Not playing on the phone.  I suspected this was the answer, but I'll hold out hope that there is a solution